# How to draw a line along the path?

Tags: tikz-pgf, paths

I'm trying to draw a red line along the existing path:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\tikz{
  \node[circle,draw] (v1) {};
  \node[circle,draw,below right of=v1] (v2) {};
  \path[draw] (v1) -- (v2);
}
\end{document}
```

How can I add the red line to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a `pic` for that.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[pics/parallel arrow/.style={code={
    \draw[-latex] (-#1) -- (#1);}}]
  \node[circle,draw] (v1) {};
  \node[circle,draw,below right of=v1] (v2) {};
  \path[draw] (v1) -- 
    pic[sloped,red,semithick,auto,swap]{parallel arrow={0.3,-0.15}} (v2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The length of the red arrow is the same as the length of the black line, correct? Is it possible to make it shorter, like in my example?

Comment: add the option `shorten` to the arrow code

Comment: @yegor256 It has the same length by accident. If you replace `0.3` by `0.25` it will become shorter. Similarly, if you replace `0.2` by `0.15` the arrow will be closer to the line.